# How to combine 2 queries in combination with 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables named "users"

```
id  name          role            
1   Mark          1
2   David         2
3   Donald        1
4   Harry         1
```

And named "events"

```
id  date        user_id
1   2020-02-01  1
2   2020-02-01  3
3   2020-02-01  2
4   2020-02-04  1
5   2020-02-01  4
```

Explanation: users can make events. If user makes an event, de event automatically gets the user_id of the user who made it. So there is a link between the id column in users and the user_id column in events.

My question: I have already a Filter option to search for events on a specific date but I want to combine this query with a query where you also can filter on the users role. So if I filter on date: 2020-02-01 and role: 1 that its echoing the next:

```
id  date         user_id
1   2020-02-01   1
2   2020-02-01   3
5   2020-02-01   4
```

How can I do this?

I've already tried the UNION function but that doesn't work:

> $query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE date = '$date' UNION SELECT *
>   FROM users WHERE role = '$role'";

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to join two table with condition right?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Please provide accounts table sturcture and it's relation to users table

Comment: @Bergin Yes you are right.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev sorry I made a typo.

Comment: on which basis you want to join your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use next query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
JOIN users ON events.user_id = users.id
WHERE events.date = '$date' AND users.role = '$role';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is where I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You should try join query instead of union

Comment: can you please add an example of how to do so?